# ActiveCell change then vaule in another cell change

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me with my macro below it doesn't work correctly when I changed value in activecell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
   
    
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    
        kolumna = ActiveCell.Column
        wiersz = ActiveCell.Row
        komorka = Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Address
        Set KeyCells = Range(komorka)
       
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Target * 12
       
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

but when I such code as below it works but it works when I change value in cell: `$D$3`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    
        Set KeyCells = Range("$D$3")
       
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Target * 12
       
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

so the problem with my code is here:

```
komorka = Cells(wiersz, kolumna).Address
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

### Move After Return

[`Application.MoveAfterReturn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.moveafterreturn)

- It will not work if `MoveAfterReturn` is set to `True`, because when you change a value the cursor moves to the next cell which becomes the `ActiveCell` so they never intersect (Correction: it will work anyway if you're in column `A` and use the <kbd>Left</kbd> arrow to confirm the entry or in `A1` use the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow, etc.).
- It could work if you set `MoveAfterReturn` to `False`, so I wrote the procedure to toggle it. Add a `Button` or a `CommandButton` and use it to enable or disable it when necessary.
- Note that you have to confirm the cell entry with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The arrows will not do.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.MoveAfterReturn Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(ActiveCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
            Dim cValue As Variant: cValue = Target.Value
            If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(cValue) * 12
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub toggleMAR()
    With Application
        If .MoveAfterReturn Then
            .MoveAfterReturn = False
        Else
            .MoveAfterReturn = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RBarry Young: Of course, my bad. Will correct it. Thanks.